when i click on delete icon content not getting deleted it is just keep loading
  FutureBuilder(
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data) {
        return IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            showLoaderDialog(context);
            await examDatabase
                .deleteExamSection(
              examId,
              snapshot.data.docs[index].id,
            );
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.delete,
            color: Theme.of(context)
                .colorScheme
                .error,
          ),
        );
      } else {
        return const SizedBox();
      }
    } else {
      return const CupertinoActivityIndicator();
    }
  },
  future: ref
      .watch(userDatabaseProvider)
      .isSuperUser(
        ref
            .watch(authServiceProvider)
            .user!
            .email
            .toString(),
      ),
),

Error deleting section:

NoSuchMethodError: Class 'bool' has no
instance getter 'docs'. I/flutter (24679): Receiver: true I/flutter
(24679): Tried calling: docs


Your future is returning boolean.

change your future condition to contain your docs instead of . isSuperUser()
